# Horizontal Scroll bar Not showing

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I have a table in a section, I need to be able to scroll the table because it has a lot of columns. This is what I tried:

```
#id_induccion_consolidado_habilitaciones {
  width: 150% !important;
}
#id_section_habilitaciones{
  display: block !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
```

But I've had no luck, this works if I try to add the scroll to a tab, but all tables/sections scroll simultaneously and I don't want this.

This is what I am working on
[image]

this is the code related to the tables mentioned. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Kx0K.png)

Comment: Please add the full code + html.

Comment: @jonathana hi, this is a platform that allows stylesheets, I only have the css. I can copy and paste everything in the console (the elements section)

Comment: you can use this tool to generate a link with your work and add it to your question: https://codverter.com/src/webeditor

Answer (score 1):

The width that you set to 150% changed it to 100% and

***try this***

```
#id_induccion_consolidado_habilitaciones {
  width: 100% !important;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```